# Command to use inside the controller's action logic to determine the route that caused that action to be invoked?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I used `rake routes` to print out all of the routes in my application.

What I found is that a couple of routes map to **the same controller/action combination**.

So in my action I would like to display **which route was actually used** to track down where everthing is coming from.

I tried just rendering `params.inspect` as text:

```
render :text => params.inspect
```

*But I don't get the route information in the hash.*

**Is there some other command to reveal the currently used route from within the action?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
request.url
```

This will tell you the route that caused your current action to be invoked.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use

`request.url` or `params[:action]` or `params[:controller]` depending on what you need.

Comment: Unless you're using subclassed controllers, Params :action/:controller are obvious given where the code is called from. They're more useful in views that can be called from multiple controllers. request.url is the correct answer.